# Why does this program not print anything in the page?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

//This program calculates how many times a number is divisible by 2.

//This is the number and the amount of times its been split into 2.

```
    let Num=64
    let divisible=0
```

//This is the ternary operator, it basically asks a question.

```
    Num % 2 === 0 ?
    divisible=divisible++ : document.write(divisible);

    Num/=2;

    Num % 2 === 0 ?
    divisible=divisible++ : document.write(divisible);

    num/=2

    Num % 2 === 0 ?
    divisible=divisible++ : document.write(divisible);
```

//Once the statement evaluates to false it writes the amount of times the number has been divided 
  by 2 into the document.

Comment: Because 64 is divisible by 2 more than just 3 times, so this never prints anything?

Comment: 64, 32, 16 are all divisible by 2. Although `num != Num` so it's just checking whether 64  and 32 are divisible by 2 and the `document.write` branches never fire. The program doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, [don't use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Why not attempt to solve your assignment by yourself first?

Comment: Btw, using a ternary operator here is not a good practice. `if`/`else` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with a loop.

```
let num=64;
let divisible=0;
while(num % 2 === 0) {
    num /= 2;
    divisible++;
}
console.log(divisible);
document.write(divisible);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this code.  Some of the comments have pointed out the looping concerns.  However, one that stands out that won't be addressed with a loop is your misuse of the [post-fix increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment), `++`.  This operator returns the value and then increments the value, so `divisible = divisible++` will result in `divisible` remaining unchanged.  Based on your intent, all you need to do is `divisible++`.

Try the following:

```js
while(true){
    if(Num % 2 === 0){
        divisible++; 
        Num /=2;
    }
    else{
        document.write(divisible); 
        break;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here as per example given for 64 and **no looping is provided , it will never go to 
document.write(divisible) statement in 3 step provided above . That's why nothing getting printed .**

Moreover , **divisible=divisible++ doesn't make any sense . Here , since it is postfix operartor , first value will be assigned then it will be incremented so value of divisible will be 0 only** .

```
Num % 2 === 0 ?divisible++ : document.write(divisible);
```

And , as per my understanding document.write **accepts string parameter** but here divisible is of number type .